# Заменить ссылки на странице

Tags: jquery

Есть много ссылок. Нужно дописать им якорь на другую страницу.

Типа такого:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var href = $('ul a').attr('href');
    var hrefGo = '/#discussion';
    var hrefNew = href + hrefGo;
    $('ul a').attr('href', hrefNew);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="feedback1">Отзывы 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="feedback2">Отзывы 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="feedback3">Отзывы 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Но у меня есть проблема. Я получаю все ссылки, но в момент редактирования, оно берет только первую ссылку и потом её же вставляет всем остальным. Как тут правильно получать и редактировать ссылки?

Comment: `$("ul a").each(function(){ $(this).attr('href',  $(this).attr('href') + '#...' ); })`

Comment: @teran спасибо, коротко и ясно, на сайте сработал :) Напиши это в ответ, я отмечу галочкой :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте `each` для перебора ссылок и изменения их значений

```
$("ul a").each(function(){ 
     var href  = $(this).attr('href') + "#discussion";
     $(this).attr('href',  href ); 
 });
```

Как вариант можно не менять ссылки, а заменить обработчик клика, который будет добавлять якорь, а потом переходить вручную.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что jQuery берет только первый элемент и по другим не ходит. Это можно решить, просто перебрав все элементы.

```
<a href="#" class="link">1</a>
<a href="#" class="link">2</a>
<a href="#" class="link">3</a>
<a href="#" class="link">4</a>
<a href="#" class="link">5</a>
<a href="#" class="link">6</a>
<a href="#" class="link">7</a>
<a href="#" class="link">8</a>
<a href="#" class="link">9</a>
<a href="#" class="link">10</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    for(let i of $("a")){
        var href = $(i).attr('href');
        var hrefGo = '/#discussion';
        var hrefNew = href + hrefGo;
        $(i).attr('href', hrefNew);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul a[href!='#']").each(function(idx, itm){
      var lastCharIdx = itm.href.length - 1,
        href = itm.href[lastCharIdx] === "/"
          ? itm.href.substr(0, lastCharIdx)
          : itm.href;
      itm.href = href + "/#discussion";
      console.log(itm.href);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="https://google.com">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://yandex.ru">link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://mail.ru">link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">not link</a></li>
</ul>
```